# Как придумать идеи для механик в Пятнашках

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Возможно задам необычный вопрос, но мне реально необходимо понять. 
Мне нужно написать пятнашки на *PyQt* на 500+ строк кода, что туда можно добавить?

Я уже сделал онлайн таблицу рекордов и возможность возвращаться на ход назад.
Заранее спасибо! Вот то, что я уже сделал.

[image: 1][image: 2]

Comment: Proksima, покажите пожалуйста что вы уже сделали.

Comment: Я добавил скрины в вопрос. Также для веб-сервера с данными я использую flask

Comment: На первом скриншоте есть меню, там есть кнопка "Windows", на неё можно нажать, там будет 2 кнопки: кнопка для отмены хода и кнопка, открывающая окно с таблицей рекордов.

Comment: Стили ещё можно добавить (белый фон квадратов, красный и пр.); размер поля (3x3, 5x5, 6x6 и другое); возможность напрямую, без закрытия/открытия, начать новую игру

Comment: Можете добавить красивую графику, цветные кнопочки

Comment: Сохранение партий

Comment: сделайте чтобы можно было игру сначала начинать

Comment: Всем спасибо! Я воспользовался вашими идеями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from random import randint 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, \
    QLabel, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPropertyAnimation, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class Game15(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self, None, Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        
        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(15):                                   
            self.buttons.append(exec(f'self._{i+1} = ...'))
            self.buttons[i] = QPushButton(self)
            self.buttons[i].clicked.connect(self._clicked)
            self.buttons[i].setText(str(i + 1))
       
        self.poss, self.font = [], QFont() 
        self.steps, self.msg_win = QLabel('st. : 0', self), QMessageBox()

        self.reload_btn = QPushButton('reload', self)
        self.reload_btn.clicked.connect(self.reload) 
        self.MV = ...

        self.mv(self, 0, 0, 'win')
        self.set_ui()
        self.reload()                                       
        
    def set_ui(self):
        self.resize(280, 400)
        self.steps.setGeometry(0, 370, 60, 30)
        self.font.setBold(1)
        self.font.setPointSize(12)
        self.reload_btn.setGeometry(180, 370, 100, 30)
        self.msg_win.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.msg_win.setFont(self.font)
        self.msg_win.setText('win')
        
        _x, _y = 0, 0
        for i in self.buttons:
            i.setFont(self.font)
            i.setGeometry(_x, _y, 70, 70)
            self.poss.append([_x, _y])
            _x, _y = (lambda a, b: (a+70, b) if a <= 140 else (0, b+70))(_x, _y)     
        
    def _clicked(self):
        for btn in self.buttons:
            if btn.hasFocus():
                k, l, c = self.ch_m(btn)
                if k:
                    self.steps.setText('st. : {}'.format(
                        int(self.steps.text()[self.steps.text().find(':') + 1:]) + 1 )
                    )
                    self.mv(btn, l, c)                      

    def ch_m(self, obj:QPushButton):
        if len([x.x() for x in self.buttons if x.y() == obj.y()]) < 4:
            for i in [0, 70, 140, 210]:
                if i not in [x.x() for x in self.buttons if x.y() == obj.y()] and \
                            obj.x() in [i+70, i-70]:
                    return [True, i, obj.y()]
        elif len([x.y() for x in self.buttons if x.x() == obj.x()]) < 4:
            for i in [0, 70, 140, 210]:
                if i not in [x.y() for x in self.buttons if x.x() == obj.x()] and \
                            obj.y() in [i+70, i-70]:
                    return [True, obj.x(), i]
        return [False, 0, 0]
        
    def mv(self, obj: QPushButton, a, b, ty='btn'):
        if ty == 'btn':
            self.MV_obj = QPropertyAnimation(obj, b'geometry')
            self.MV_obj.setDuration(100)
            self.MV_obj.setStartValue(QRect(obj.x(), obj.y(), obj.width(), obj.height()))
            self.MV_obj.setEndValue(QRect(a, b, obj.width(), obj.height()))
            self.MV_obj.finished.connect(self.check)
            self.MV_obj.start()
        elif ty == 'win':
            self.MV_obj = QPropertyAnimation(obj, b'windowOpacity')
            self.MV_obj.setDuration(2000)
            self.MV_obj.setStartValue(0)
            self.MV_obj.setEndValue(10)
            self.MV_obj.start()
            obj.show()
            
    def reload(self):
        s_l: list = self.poss.copy()
        for i in self.buttons:
            r = randint(0, len(s_l) - 1)        
            p = s_l.pop(r)
            i.setGeometry(p[0], p[1], 70, 70)
    
    def check(self):
        if [[a.x(), a.y()] for a in self.buttons] == self.poss:
            self.msg_win.setText('win\n\n steps: {}'.format(
                int(self.steps.text()[self.steps.text().find(':') + 1:]))
            )

            self.mv(self.msg_win, 0, 0, 'win')
            self.msg_win.finished.connect(self.reload)
            self.steps.setText('st. : 0')
          

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Game15()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Можно добавить больше стилей. Например, деревянный. Очень даже ничего смотрится кстати. Или вот такой, по типу металла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуй использовать .setStyleSheet, очень полезная штука. С помощью него можно фон добавить, закругления углов и даже, если ничего не путаю, можно добавить градиент 0_о. Я это всё обычно настраиваю в QtDesigner'е (Загугли, реально тема топ кста, намного быстрее можно сделать нормальный интерфейс без мучений с настройкой координат у каждой кнопки). В самом коде не помню как применяется.